# How can I use the TFS Online <--> Azure Website integration when there are two web apps in the solution

Tags: azure, web-deployment, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops

I am trying to get continuous integration configured using Azure. The process I have followed is exactly as detailed by [Continuous delivery to Windows Azure using Visual Studio Online](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continous-delivery-use-tfs/)

This process works perfectly! I check-in, it builds, and deploys to the Azure website. However, as soon as I add a second web application to the solution, after the CI build kicks off and then completes, the only thing that gets published to the website is the bin directory of the second web application! (Updates to the first project are successful, though)

Given the scenario, I don't understand why the dll's of the second application are being published to the bin directory when the rest of the application(i.e. content files) are not. There is no reference from app1 to app2 so the dll's shouldn't be brought in by reference.

How can I configure this so that it will also publish the second web application?

Comment: Thanks! That saves me hours of banging my head while trying to figure out what I've set up incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell Windows Azure Web Sites which project within a repository to deploy using a deployment file.

Add a file called `.deployment` to the root directory of your repository, with this content:

```
[config]
project = src/MyApp.Web
```

You can specify the folder containing the web application, or the actual .csproj or .vbproj file for the application.

If you have two sites in a single solution/repository and you want to publish them both, you will need to use two separate Web Sites, and use App Settings in the portal to specify the project instead. Create the sites, and for each, add a setting called `Project` in the Configure page, with the path to the directory or project as before.

More info: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments (Kudu is the system that actually handles deployments on Azure Web Sites)

Comment: Sweet! I had actually given up hope and started using publish profiles. I will give this a try either later tonight or tomorrow and accept this as the answer if all goes well. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that the Kudu system does NOT handle VSO build's; that is done by the TFS Build system, therefore this setting is not applicable. https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/VSO-vs-Kudu-deployments